# how can i rotate image displayed on html button

Tags: html, css, imagebutton

hey I have refresh button in HTML and i want to rotate the image on that button when I click it. I have created effects using css as follows:

```
 input.button_refresh {

margin-left: 600px;
background: url("../images/refresh.JPG") 0 0 no-repeat scroll ;
background-position: right;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: rgb(80,140,210);
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
height: 20px; /* height of the background image */
width: 70px; /* width of the background image */
color: threedface;
border-radius: 6em;
 }
```

HTML

```
<input type="image" name="Refresh" value="Refresh" class="button_refresh" onclick="window.location.reload()" />
```

Comment: if there is no text in button just rotate the button on :active using css3 transform.

Comment: @SVS ya there is text on button

Comment: CSS3 is not fully supported yet, I would recommend you to create active pseudo acctive class, rotate the image yourself using some photo editor and use it, surely you wont't get smooth moment but it'll support all browsers

Comment: <input type="image" name="Refresh" value="Refresh" class="button_refresh" onclick="window.location.reload()" />    Here is code..

Comment: is your image 20px in height and 70px in width???

Comment: @arttronics don't you think that height, and width will be applied to the button instead of image?

Comment: Both, but I hazard the image is clipped?

Comment: i have text and image both on button

Comment: even threedface is not supported by all browsers, this markup will have incompatibility issues with different browsers

Comment: is it possible to rotate image??

Comment: rotate it using active pseudo..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
input.button_refresh:active {
  background: url("../images/otherImage.JPG") 0 0 no-repeat scroll ; /* other image or rotated image */
}
```

Check this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zbq9z/)

Edit : Added a Demo

Comment: It should be working. check the updated demo.. Click on the button,the image changes..

Answer (score 0):

Hi think you can follow Alien's way. In addition to that you can keep a flag and accordingly rotate the image by calling the particular css class.